# how to use .csb file after published project from cocostudio

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocostudio

I have created a UI for my game.
after published project from cocostudio I have got .csb file.
how to use it in my game?

Answer (score 5):

```
Add the header file
```

#include"cocostudio.h"

Node* node = CSLoader::createNode("background.csb");

```
this->addChild(node);

//get animation data

cocostudio::timeline::ActionTimeline* action = CSLoader::createTimeline("background.csb");

node->runAction(action);

action->gotoFrameAndPlay(0, true);
```

it will be helpful for you

Comment: Thank for you help.    Is there a cocos2d-js version for this? I have google it but I cant find it any more.

Comment: you can download the latest version v3.1 it supported cocostudiohttp://www.cocos2d-x.org/download

Comment: no, I have use cocos2d-js now. and I think cocostudio is not support cocos2d-js now.

Comment: Cocos2d-JS v3.0 is compatible with Cocos Studio v1.2 - v2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Example with js:

```
    var node = ccs.csLoader.createNode("res/node.csb");
    var node_action = ccs.actionTimelineCache.createAction("res/node.csb");
    node.runAction(node_action);
    node.attr({
        scale: 0.6,
        x: 130,
        y: 10,
    })
    node_action.gotoFrameAndPlay(0, 40, true);
    this.addChild(node);
```

Comment: thanks how ever there is an error. "TypeError: ccs.csLoader is undefined"

Comment: @DDa you should add "extensions" to the modules list in your project.json

Comment: This is now: var cssResource = css.load("res/node.csb"); this.addChild(cssResource.node)